# Error in exported data's format from Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, spyder

I managed to import & export the data with some minimal changes but in the exported file the data is not in the format as it was expected. Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

```
#Data Cleaning/Pre-Processing
import pandas as pd

url = r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\samples\olympic-medals\medals.csv"
bf = pd.read_csv(url)
exe = bf.dropna(subset = ['Sport'], axis = 0, inplace = True)
bf.rename(columns = {'Year':'NewYear'}, inplace = True)
bf.to_csv(r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DS\IBM\Lab 1\imports1.csv", sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
print (bf)
```

**Expected:**

[image]

**Actual:**

[image]

*Note: Data is correct, only not in format, thanks.*

Comment: do you have the same values when you open it up in an editor that's not excel? MS Excel will infer `\t` and open appropriately try `sep='|`` or open in notepad

Comment: Hi @Datanovice, Yes it is the same data only but id I'm adding sep = '|' it is just adding a separator after each value, not taking as a column, thanks

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/11301900

Comment: Why are you using the `sep` parameter? Just use: `bf.to_csv(r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DS\IBM\Lab 1\imports1.csv", encoding='utf-8')`, that should work fine

Comment: You can also export the file as a `tsv` file (tab separated values):
`bf.to_csv(r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\DS\IBM\Lab 1\imports1.tsv", sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: Hi @jlewkovich Yes, it works without separator. Thank you very much have a nice day!